# Need to get the timestamp using Tableview config

Tags: mule, tableview, config, export-to-csv

Currently I'm working on the Collibra with Mule to export data as reports.
My requiremnt to export the data from the Collibra to external file.
For this I'm using the tableview config with Mule &collibra connect.
which using the **exportCSV** am able to get the data in format dd/mm/yyyy but I need the time stamp with date.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The DGC Connector can be used to import the CSV that resulted from converting the external data.
The important part here, is the Table View Config that specifies how DGC has to interpret the CSV data and map it to DGC concepts.You have to configure the Table View Config as follows:
Asset (Term) ID should be the unique identifier of the DGC Assets. You can get that ID from the mapping information.
The default operation has to be UPDATE, to cope with the scenarios described earlier. You already created the asset, so you do not have to CREATE anything anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Mule dataweave can be used to convert the time from dd/mm/yyyy to the corresponding timestamp